# Actualizar campo archivo desde PHP en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Tengo una tabla que guarda los nombres de los responsables de unas actas, así que una vez firmada el acta la subo para que quede dentro de la columna del responsable. Pero al intentar subir el acta me aparece esto:

[image: Resultado del envío]

Este es el `UPDATE` que tengo:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["acta"]))                               
           $acta = ($_FILES['acta']);
        else
            $acta =NULL;
    $orden=intval($_POST['mod_orden']);

    $sql="UPDATE asignacion_pc SET Nombre='".$nombre."', Cargo='".$cargo."', Equipo='".$equipo."', Cedula='".$cedula."', Celular='".$celular."', condicion='".$condicion."', estado='".$estado."', acta='".$acta."' WHERE orden='".$orden."';";
```

Y la base de datos:

[image: Esquema de la base de datos]

**Actualizado**

```
<?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal20" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Entrega de equipo corporativo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="editar_asignacion_pc" name="editar_asignacion_pc" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="asignacion_pc">

        <div id="resultados_ajax2"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Nombre2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre2" name="Nombre2" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                <input type="hidden" id="mod_orden" name="mod_orden">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Cargo2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cargo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cargo2" name="Cargo2" placeholder="Cargo" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Equipo2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Equipo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control" name="Equipo2" id='Equipo2' required>
              <option value="">Seleccione un equipo</option>  
              <option value="Lenovo Thinkpad E460">Lenovo Thinkpad E460</option>
              <option value="Lenovo Thinkcenter">Lenovo Thinkcenter</option>       
              <option value="HP prodesk 600 g1 sff">HP prodesk 600 g1 sff</option> 
              <option value="HP probook 430 G3">HP probook 430 G3</option>
              <option value="HP Pavilion x360">HP Pavilion x360</option> 
              <option value="HP probook 450g">HP probook 450g</option>         
              </select>
               </div>
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Cedula2" class="col-sm-3 control- 
        label">Cedula</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cedula2" 
         name="Cedula2" placeholder="Cedula" required>
            </div>
          </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Celular2" class="col-sm-3 control- 
               label">Celular</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Celular2" 
                name="Celular2" placeholder="Celular" required>
            </div>
          </div>    
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="condicion2" class="col-sm-3 control- 
                label">Condicion</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <select class='form-control' name='condicion2' 
               id='condicion2' required>
                    <option value="">Seleccione un Tipo de 
                 condicion</option>
                    <option value="Nuevo">Nuevo</option>
                    <option value="Usado">Usado</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="estado2" class="col-sm-3 control- 
                 label">Estado</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <select class='form-control' name='estado2' id='estado2' 
                 required>
                    <option value="">Seleccione un Tipo de estado</option>
                    <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
                    <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="acta" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Acta</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="acta" type="file" name="acta" > 
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Codigo HTML por favor.

Comment: Cual codigo el del popup?

Comment: seria bueno que pongas el codigo del el modal de donde estas enviado los datos..

Comment: ok ya subo el code

Comment: Hace falta agregar el atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'` al formulario como primera medida :)

Comment: ok ya lo agregue

Comment: Persiste el error ?  además faltaría el `action`  en su formulario

Comment: si persiste el error, pero entonces porque los otros campos si se actualizan?

Comment: a mi parecer el problema esta en el update pero no estoy seguro

Comment: y puse el action y tampoco me sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: no veo en ningun lado que has puesto el multi `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: listo ya lo puse

Comment: que tal te funciono?

Comment: no no funciono ya lo habia probado antes pero no lo habia actualizado aqui

Comment: ¿Estás usando mysqli o PDO/MySQL?

Comment: mysqli y mysql porque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de añadir el enctype que te ya te han comentado, si quieres guardar el File como blob debes recoger su contenido.

```
$acta = file_get_contents($_FILES["acta"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Comment: ese remplazaria al        if(isset($_FILES["acta"]))                               
                         $acta = ($_FILES['acta']);
                 else
                $acta =NULL;

Comment: Sería el caso si cumple la condición del if

Comment: ok voy a probar.. desaparecio un error pero se quedo este  

            $ruta_tmp = $_FILES['acta']['tmp_name'];

lo mismo undefined index

Comment: Haz un var_dump de $_FILES a ver si sale algo en claro

Comment: No esta trayendo nada    

array(0) { }

Comment: Estoy pensando, pero no se me ocurre por qué no envía el archivo. No hay otro campo que se llame acta y pueda interferir, no?

Comment: no solo ese pero tampoco se anteriormente hice uno igual pero en vez de actualizar lo hice con datos nuevos y me corre perfecto